# Android. Как сохранить Context в SharedPreferences, и потом извлечь его?

Tags: java, android

Есть такой [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32979949/1776312), как запускать поиск и отправку координат раз в пять минут по будильнику, но если приложение закрыть клавишей `back`, то отправка довольно быстро прекратится, потому, что будет возникать ошибка в классе `LocationTracker.java`

так-как:

```
Location currentLocation = LocationProvider.getInstance().getCurrentLocation();
```

Будет давать `null`.

Я думаю это происходит потому, что в *синглтон* `LocationProvider.java` теряется `Context`после закрытия приложения. После ошибки, *синглтон* пытается работать с другим `Context`, но взаимодействия не получается так-как `Context` уже другой.

Я прав?

Как сохранить `Context` в `SharedPreferences`, чтобы достать и подставить его в *синглтон*, когда приложение с контекстом закрыты?

Comment: Вам всего лишь надо использовать Service.

Comment: А если без Service?

Comment: Почему без? Это принципиально в Вашей задаче? Или вы ни разу не работали с ним или же хотите придумать очередной костыль?

Comment: Если все по будильнику запускается, то не хочу чтоб сервис еще висел.

Comment: А чем вам не нравится вариант с сервисом который просто делает `sleep()` на 5 минут своему потоку?

Comment: @anber, глупая идея со "sleep() на 5 минут", намного лучше написать грамотно BroadcastReceiver, который будет ловить интенты от AlarmManager, в который мы заранее установим PendingIntent с переодичностью в 5 минут. Это лучше тем, что система система может вырубить наш сервис, а вот системный AlarmManager будет работать, даже при спящем режиме, т.к. он будит процессор и выкидывает наш PendingIntent. А BroadcastReceiver получает наш интент с данными и context. По факту, context, который получает BroadcastReceiver можно использовать в своих целях. Например  передавая его в configureIfNeeded(ctx)

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко Ну в принципе я того же мнения - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461932/176928

Answer (score 3):

> Как сохранить Context в SharedPreferences чтоб достать и подставить
>   его в сингелтон, когда приложение с контекстом закрыты?

Никак. Он содержит информацию о текущем состоянии окружения, и даже если вам бы удалось записать его куда либо при восстановлении он устаревшим.

По поводу того почему этот код перестает работать - спросите у автора ответа на который вы ссылаетесь, он там написал довольно большую обертку, и мне не хочется в ней копаться.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, вам нужно в BroadcastReceiver (пример из ссылки) вот это:

```
Location currentLocation = LocationProvider.getInstance().getCurrentLocation();
```

заменить на :

```
LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance();
locationProvider.configureIfNeeded(сontext); 
Location currentLocation = locationProvider.getCurrentLocation();
```

А null вы получаете так как в примере

```
private static Location currentLocation;
```

не инициализировано.

Comment: К сожалению не помогает, context после ошибки меняется и currentLocation получает null.

Comment: Контекст меняется и экземпляр класса пересоздается, у него пустое поле, оно не успевает обновиться!!! Вы делаете запрос на обновление, а пока запрос не успевает отработать вы сразу же запрашиваете локацию, вот вам и null. Контекст тут не причем, я могу вам посоветовать потратить время и все же разобраться откуда берутся координаты, как туда относится контекст и вообще что такое Context.