# Постоянная работа в background в Android даже когда GUI закрыт

Tags: android

Делаю приложение, которое с будет с GUI и которое также должно постоянно работать в фоне даже если сам GUI закрыт/destroyed/suspended. Оно должно стартовать автоматически при загрузке телефона.

В фоне оно будет отправлять данные на сервер, скажем, каждые 10 секунд.

Погуглив, я пришел к выводу что один из способ сделать это - Service. А второй - ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. Остальные не подходят (alarm manager, timer, handler).

Что посоветуете? Какой из этих способов выбрать? Какой лучше для моей задачи?

Comment: Почему AlarmManager не подходит?

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, не знаю, но мне так показалось судя по ответам на других форумах.

Comment: Service-AarmManager-BroadcastReceiver. Вот три компонента для вашей реализации

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, а подробнее? Почему они? Почему не ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` это обертка над `ThreadPoolExecutor` из `java.util.concurrent`. С тем же успехом можно использовать обычный `Thread`.

`Service` же разработан специально для Android с учетом специфики lifecycle Android приложений.

Comment: ну и что выбрать? service?

Comment: ну и что выбрать? service?

Comment: Из предложенных вами вариантов - Service. Более того это будет самая простая реализация. Но в плане эффективности я более склоняюсь к alarm manager. У него основное преимущество в том что он запустится даже если если процесс вашего приложения убит. Кроме того, я еще не тестировал как сервисы ведут себя на андроиде 6.0 с новой системой экономии заряда батареи DOZE, но есть подозрение что она может гасить постоянно работающий сервис.

Answer (score 1):

В общем план таков, используйте **BroadcastReceiver** для автозагрузки приложения при включении телефона, об этом почитайте [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/165-urok-100-service-intentservice-foreground-avtozagruzka-servisa.html), а для фоновой посылки каждые 10 секунд используйте **AlarmManager**, о нём почитайте [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html). В итогде при старте телефона вам прилетит интент в **BroadcastReceiver**, а уже из него вы запулите **AlarmManager** и плов готов!

Comment: выше мне посоветовали использовать service и я тоже к нему склонялся. разве его не нужно нигде использовать вообще в моем случае?

Comment: Честное слово, тут всё зависит от самой задачи и конструкторского решения самого человека, который это всё программирует, если сильно нужно, то делайте через сервисы, это ж от задачи всё зависит, но по вашему вопросу я так себе вижу решение вашей проблему. Просто чтобы понять через что лучше, вам нужно почитать про все 3 класса и понять их суть, потом подумать что вы хотите и принять решение, что вам из этого набора лучше всего подходит

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать BroadcastReceiver для запуска приложения при включении телефона. И **Foreground** Service, в котором есть таймертаск, который выполняет что-либо раз в N времени.

Comment: что за foreground service?

Comment: @MariusKavansky это такой сервис, который будет работать всегда, даже если Активити убита, даже если нехватает памяти.

Comment: разве не все сервисы такие?

Comment: @MariusKavansky Нет